# Semi-automatic function vectorization (Julia)

Tags: macros, julia, vectorization, metaprogramming

I'd like to (somehow) generate methods that dispatch when a function is called with *one* vector argument, starting from a "template".

My particular use case is plotting. I have a function that plots the behavior of a system defined by several scalar parameters, like this:

```julia
function myplot(a::Number, b::Number, c::Number)
    results = calculate(a, b, c)
    plot(results; xlabel="X Label", ylabel="Y Label", label="Signal")
end
```

[image]

I want to extend this method to explore how changing *one* parameter (a, b, or c) affects the behavior of this system.

The built-in vectorization with dot-calls (i.e., `my plot.([a1 a2 a3], b, c`) produces multiple plots. However, I would like to draw these as subplots within a single figure instead, while tweaking some subplot parameters to make it pretty. This is trivial to do for one parameter, like `a`:

```julia
function myplot(as::AbstractVecOrMat{T}, b::Number, c::Number) where T <: Number
    plots = []
    for (ix, a) in enumerate(as)
        results = calculate(a, b, c)
        push!(plots, plot(results;
            label=ix==1 ? "Signal" : nothing,
            xlabel=ix==length(as) ? "X Label" : "")
    end

    plot(plots...; layout=grid(length(plots), 1), plot_title="Effects of varying a")
end
```

[image]

**What is the best way to create similar functions for visualizing changes in `b` or `c`?** These would be identical, except for a) the signature, b) the loop variable, and c) the plot_title. Copy-and-paste is one obvious option, but feels inelegant. Another option would be to make the vectorized version take *only* vectors. However, it is slightly annoying to provide [x] instead of x, and this visualization can be misleading if multiple parameters vary at the same time.

It feels like there must be an elegant metaprogramming/macro solution, but I can't quite figure it out.

[Code](https://gist.github.com/mrkrause/a894c37334f769775cfbac3b01dd446c)

Comment: What do you want to happen with multiple vector parameters -- broadcast behaviour, or cartesian product?

Comment: Ideally nothing! I was hoping to specifically generate myplot(a::Vector{T}, b::Real, c::Real), myplot(a::Real, b::Vector{T}, c::Real), and myplot(a::Real, b::Real, c::Vector{T}).

Comment: How important is it to fail if more than one is a vector? These three functions could be implemented by one function that either `broadcast`s or takes an `Iterators.product` of the three arguments -- but then the question is, what happens when there's more than linearly many combinations

Comment: I thought about that! It's not a showstopper--and I like that you can provide either a scalar or vector for each parameter, but I thought it'd be nicer if the (IMO) confusing plots that result from having multiple vector args weren't even an option.

Answer (score 3):

I would use `Iterators.product` and check if the result is dimension at most one. `Number` is automatically a zero-dimensional container of `Number`. One thing to be aware here is that if you pass in a matrix argument it will also fail the `ndims` check, since matrixes add two dimensions.

```
function myplot(as, bs, cs)
    plots = []
    it = Iterators.product(as, bs, cs)
    if ndims(it) > 1
        error("multiple iterables passed, or iterables of too high dimension")
    end
    for (ix, (a, b, c)) in enumerate(it)
        results = calculate(a, b, c)
        push!(plots, plot(results;
            label=ix==1 ? "Signal" : nothing,
            xlabel=ix==length(as) ? "X Label" : "")
    end

    plot(plots...; layout=grid(length(plots), 1), plot_title="Effects of varying a")
end
```

Demonstrating using a print statement:

```
julia> myplot(1, 2, 3)
1 2 3

julia> myplot([1, 2, 3], 2, 3)
1 2 3
2 2 3
3 2 3

julia> myplot([1, 2], 3, [4, 5])
ERROR: multiple iterables passed, or iterables of too high dimension
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(s::String)
   @ Base ./error.jl:33
 [2] myplot(as::Vector{Int64}, bs::Int64, cs::Vector{Int64})
   @ Main ./REPL[12]:5
 [3] top-level scope
   @ REPL[16]:1
```